# Does my Macbook Pro 15" Late 2013 Geekbench 4 score indicate a faulty discrete GPU?

Tags: macbook-pro, performance, gpu, benchmark

According to my Geekbench 4 results, my discrete GPU Open CL score is ZERO.

Additionally, my discrete GPU Metal score is lower than that for the Iris Pro!

**Does this mean my duscrete GPU is faulty?**

Below are screenshots of my device and results, and here is a link to my Geekbench results online: https://browser.geekbench.com/v4/compute/2415138

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: What exactly does it make weird to you?

Comment: @nohillside Discrete GPU Open CL score is ZERO. Additionally, discrete GPU Metal score is lower than Iris Pro!

Comment: Please edit the question to make it more clear

Comment: @nohillside Done!

Comment: For the "0" score issue see this discussion on primatelabs.com: http://support.primatelabs.com/discussions/geekbench/23880-zero-opencl-score - "We’ve contacted Apple regarding this issue and Apple’s response is that they are unable to address the issue due to reduced NVIDIA support. "

Answer (score 1):

**Short Answer**

Your discrete GPU is almost certainly fine. The reason for the zero score is that Geekbench is unable to fully test this GPU due to reduced NVIDIA support. Because it can't run a full test, you're getting a score of zero, but this does **not** mean your GPU is faulty.

**Long Answer**

According to your [Geekbench results](https://browser.geekbench.com/v4/compute/2415138), you scored a Depth of Field result of zero because it measured 0.00 pixels/sec for that metric. In other words, Geekbench itself is unable to test this metric, rather than there being an issue with your discrete GPU.

This is a known issue. According to Primate Labs:

> This is due to an issue with the NVIDIA GPU drivers provided with macOS. We’ve contacted Apple regarding this issue and Apple’s response is that they are unable to address the issue due to reduced NVIDIA support.

<sup>Source: [Primate Labs Support: Zero OpenCL Score](http://Zero%20OpenCL%20Score)</sup>

I did [check](https://www.geforce.com/drivers) to see if there were any drivers you could download directly from NVIDIA, but non are available for macOS.

**So, unless you're actually experiencing any problems using your MBP, I would just ignore this score altogether.**

Comment: Thank you very much! It is NVIDIA GeForce GT 750M with 2GB of GDDR5 memory.

Comment: @Yossiri Is that not the internal, but discrete GPU?  I can't imagine that you would use that model as external GPU (connected via Thunderbolt).

Comment: Yossiri, I'm just catching up with my messages and @Redarm raises a good point. Your MBP comes with two graphics cards, an integrated GPU (the Intel Iris Pro 5200) and a dedicated GPU (the NVIDIA GeForce GT 750M). However, the way your question reads, I've interpreted it as though you've also invested in an external GPU (which is another thing altogether). Can you clarify? If you're only talking about the built-in graphics cards, then yes, Geekbench 4 can benchmark these. If you're talking about an external GPU, then that's another thing and what I've been in discussions with Primate Labs on.

Comment: Thank you Monometh and Redarm. I used the wrong word. I already corrected it. So does it indicate a faulty discrete GPU?

Comment: I've just updated my answer. In short, your discrete GPU should be fine! :)